# Python - Always append certain strings to the end of a list

Tags: python, list

I've hit a wall and needed some help or advice to get me through.

I want to append certain strings always apppend to the end of a list.

So we have

```
List1 = ["sony","cant recall","samsung","dont know","apple","no answer", "toshiba"]
```

Next we have another list

```
List2 = ["dont know", "cant recall","no answer"]
```

Here is what I've developed so far. The script basically checks if the word in List 1 is in List 2, if found, that particular string should be moved from its current location in the list to the end. But all I can do for now is find the string and its index. I dont know how to move and append the found string to the end of the list.

```
for p, item in enumerate(list1):
    for i, element in enumerate(list2):
        if item == element:
            print item, p
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your algorithm like:

```
 list1 = [x for x in list1 if not x in list2] + [x for x in list1 if x in list2]
```

which will result in:

```
['sony', 'samsung', 'apple', 'toshiba', 'cant recall', 'dont know', 'no answer']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst_result = set(lst1) | set(lst2)
```

Removes duplicates from the lists as a side effect. Not sure if you want it, but looks like it's assumed.

To keep the ordering:

```
lst1 = ["sony","cant recall","samsung","dont know","apple", "toshiba"]
lst2 = ["dont know", "cant recall","no answer"]

stripped = list(filter(lambda x: x not in lst2,lst1))
lst_result = stripped + lst2
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
for item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        list1.remove(item)
        list1.append(item)
```

Comment: Be careful, this won't work if you have two consecutive items from list1 in list 2 (try with list1 = ["sony","cant recall","dont know", "samsung", "apple", "no answer", "toshiba"]) for example.
[Directly removing an item from a list while iterating it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python) is not the best solution.